# Win32 - xCode 4.3.3

Tags: c++, xcode, winapi

I'm fairly new to C++/OpenGL etc.

I'm currently learning in xCode on an Apple Mac.
I know the headers for the Glut files etc are different (which was one problem i was having a while back).

Is there a way to use Win32 etc? I'm using xCode 4.3.3. Thanks.

Comment: You want to create an application for Windows through XCode, that is fine, but why to use it as your IDE?

Comment: This was a genuine question and i've done a bunch of research yet i'm getting down voted? Now i can no longer ask questions. I've built up a good catalogues of Questions over the last couple of months. Please vote up :(

Comment: Cant you remove your question?

Comment: Downvote means, in this case, this is a really unimportant and uninteresting question.  It could also be a mark of the community saying, "hey we don't want a million questions like this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 is Microsoft's Windows API. Using this on a Mac would require more than a plug-in for Xcode; it would require an independent implementation of Win32.

There are some non-Microsoft implementations of Win32 such as Wine, however these are geared toward compatibility with executable built for Windows using Window's toolchains rather than allowing people that know or want to use Win32 to build Mac Apps. With Clang's natural cross-compile support there may well be a way to make it work, but it seems like a convoluted method of writing Mac apps, to say the least.

Instead, for the parts of your programs that rely on OS specific APIs you should find tutorials or documentation for OS X's APIs. For the parts that are specific to OpenGL you can use tutorials made for Windows, but you'll need to know how to recognize which parts apply portably to OpenGL, are OpenGL that have to be modified for other platforms*, or are Windows specific.

<sub>`*` For example last time I did OpenGL for Windows the latest headers were for OpenGL 1.1 and everything else had to be done through extensions rather than according to the latest OpenGL spec, or one had to use third party headers to make using extensions look like standard OpenGL.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not real because you will need virtualize MacOSX libs.
If you using ony standart C++, you can (or maybe port your application to macosx).
XCode only for Macs.

Comment: He can use xcode as IDE for C and C++ files... he don't need to use obj-c at all.